# React Admin - Create table from Array

Tags: javascript, react-admin

I need to create a table and handle the data on the front end, handle an array, if user clicks something, I will remove the item from the array and the table will remove the row from it.

I need to create a simple table, like List component, but, passing it an array, I have checking the component ArrayField, but I dont understand how React Admin knows which array I want to pass it.

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#arrayfield

Is this possible?

Im thinking about create a new table all with Material-UI and avoid to use List component for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely NOT use react-admin's `<List>` or `<Datagrid>` for this use case - they are designed to use the dataProvider as datasource.

Writing your own table with material-ui components is the way to go.